# Нужна ли запятая при приложении?

Tags: приложение, пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая:

> Эту ксерокопию в областном архиве
> сделал один из самых активных
> общественных корреспондентов, кандидат
> экономических наук В.Лычагин.

Вроде бы неоднородные приложения, но без запятой как-то не звучит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы тоже поставила, даже тире бы поставила:

> Эту ксерокопию в областном архиве
> сделал один из самых активных
> общественных корреспондентов -
> кандидат экономических наук В.Лычагин.

Можно ведь и так рассуждать: Кто? - один из корреспондентов - подлежащее. Кто именно? - В.Лычагин - уточняющее подлеж. Кто он по профессии, какое звание? - кандидат экономических наук. Но звание ПЕРЕД уточняющим подлежащим.

Comment: спасибо огромное.

Answer (score 3):

Эту ксерокопию в областном архиве сделал один из самых активных общественных корреспондентов, кандидат экономических наук В.Лычагин.

Неоднородные приложения вообще  РЕДКО ВСТРЕЧАЮТСЯ, особенно  в художественных и публицистических текстах, что связано с трудностью определения  синтаксической роли слов; поэтому этот вариант характерен только для  определенных тематических групп, например: "Научную работу возглавил заведующий кафедрой профессор Сорокин А.А".

В остальных случаях это однородные приложения, обозначающие сближенные признаки и раскрывающие общую тему-характеристику какого-либо лица.